# Loop through elements of a separate HTML file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I loop through elements of a separate HTML file using JQuery?

So far I have this:

```
var x = $('<div>').load('<separate html file> #<id>');
console.log(x[0]);
```

Now I'd like to loop through the elements in variable `x`. Preferably using a `JQuery each loop`.

`x` holds a list of elements from the `<separate html file>` each with the `<id>` specified.

The output of `console.log(x[0])` looks something like this (where `<id>` is the id specified above:

```
<div>
    <div id=<id> >Stuff</div>
    <div id=<id> >Stuff</div>
    <div id=<id> >Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, what's there to loop over?

Comment: @j08691 the `.load` function returns a list of elements. Its to loop over these.

Comment: use the .load('url').done(function(result){$(result).find('div')})

Comment: @romuleald Error: `done is not a function`

Comment: Wow, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @romuleald `3.1.1`

Comment: oh wait sorry, this is .load like insert data inside, `x`should be you parent div, so you could use x.find('div')

Comment: That should be a closing `</div>` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to wait until the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) operation is complete and you do this by setting up a success callback function.

Next, you'll need to have something to loop over. I'm assuming that your result is more HTML, so we can loop through the [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) of the container.

Finally, you can perform the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop:

```js
// Perform the load operation (hard-coded response here) and supply a success callback:
var x =  $( "#result" ).load(
      "<div><div id=1 >Stuff</div><div id=2>Stuff</div><div id=3>Stuff</div><div>", function() {
   
        // Find the first div element within the container and loop through its children
        $("#result").find("div").children().each(function(){
          // Access the element and do whatever you need to:
          console.log(this); 
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  <div>
    <div id=1 >Stuff</div>
    <div id=2>Stuff</div>
    <div id=3>Stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer.

Comment: LOL. Time for a coffee break! Thanks again.

Comment: I still cant get the children of variable `x` using your method.

Comment: I"m not using `x` in my example. What is the content of the `load` response? Is it HTML?

Comment: no need to search dom for same element ... `$(this)` is `$('#result')`

Comment: Don't set a variable to the result of the `load`. Access the container in the callback function.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I know, but I thought it would be better to show what we're getting the children of to the OP.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've updated my answer to include the content of the load response.

Comment: @sudoman See my updated code snippet answer that shows this working.

Comment: I implemented it without the `.children()` function because I was looking for something with a particular id. Thanks!

Comment: @sudoman You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote as well. Good luck!